# Correctness of a certain physical model for calculating the lift acting on a spinning and stationary frisbee

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, flow, aerodynamics, lift

I just wanted to check if the fundamental physical principles of the following calculation of the aerodynamic lift acting on a rotating frisbee without translational motion, are correct. I assume a "frisbee" to be a truncated cone (with a trapez cross section) with inner radius $R$. When I refer to the disk part of the frisbee, i mean the flat part of the frisbee.

The lift force acting on the spinning frisbee with angular speed $\Omega$ is caused in the following way: as a result of the rotation of the disk, the air layer next to it begins to rotate, and because of the centrifugal acceleration associated with the rotation, the air begins to flow radialy out, and when it reaches the edge of the disk it is than deflected downward by the conical part of the frisbee, thereby creating upward force (according to Newton's third law).

My model uses the conception of the "Eckman boundary layer" to describe the air layer that is adjacent to the rotating disk. The model describes the tangential and radial flow of air in the rotating frame of reference of the frisbee. Therefore, Coriolis and centrifugal forces are included. Mathematically, the model is based on the simultanous solution of the following two coupled differential equations for $u_r(r,z),u_{\varphi}(r,z)$ ($r$ is the radial distance from the center of the frisbee, and $z$ the vertical coordinate):

$$-2\Omega u_r = \frac{\eta}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2 u_{\varphi}}{\partial z^2}$$
$$2\Omega u_{\varphi}+\Omega^2r = \frac{\eta}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2u_r}{\partial z^2}$$

and the boundary conditions:

$$u_r(z=0)=u_{\varphi}(z=0)=0$$
$$u_r(z=-\infty)=0$$
$$u_{\varphi}(z=-\infty)=-\Omega r$$.

I didn't include the solution of those differential equations, but it's very simple (basically a product of decaying exponents and cosine functions). The basic idea is that the radial flow profile $u_r(r,z)$ has a maximum at certain value of $z$ and than it decays rapidly. The thickness of that boundary layer ("Eckman layer") is $d=\sqrt{\frac{\eta}{\Omega \rho}}$ up to a small constant factor. After solving the equations, one gets that the vertically averaged radial outward flow $u_r(R)$ at the edge of the frisbee (at $r=R$) is approximately $\Omega R$ (again, up to a constant factor). Therefore, if the angle of attack of  the conical frisbee is $\alpha$ (the angle between the generating line of the conical surface and the horizonal plane), than the lift force $L$ is equal to:

$$L = \frac{1}{2}C\rho d(2\pi R) (\Omega R)^2 sin\alpha = \pi C\sqrt{\rho \eta \Omega^3}  R^3 sin\alpha $$,

where $C$ is a constant numerical factor.

**Calculation for a typical frisbee**

On average, air has density $\rho=1.2kg/m^3$ and viscosity $\eta=1.81\cdot 10^{-5}kg/(m\cdot sec)$. For a typical frisbee with radius $R=0.15m$, angle of attack $\alpha \approx 90$ and angular frequency $f=6-8Hz$ ($\Omega = 2\pi f$), than setting $C$ to be $0.5$ and using my formula results in a lift force $L$ of only about $0.01 Newton $, which is about one percent of the weight of a typical frisbee (with $m=0.165kg$). Therefore, for daily scenarios, the lift caused by spinning is quite neglible, but it's still interesting to examine the problem theoreticaly.

However, in contrast to air (which has very low density and viscosity), spinning in water can generate quite large lift, as water are 1000 times denser than air and 100 times more viscous. With a powerful engine that rotates the frisbee at angular frequency of more than $100Hz$, and a disk radius of $R=0.5m$, this can generate $3100N$ of lift (enough to elevate a $300kg$ weight). It is interesting to check if this concept of propulsion was explored throughly by aerodynamicists, especially from the point of view of thrust to power ratio.

**Question**

Now, i have one problematic issue with this model:

- This model doesn't take into acount the pressure distribution at the surface of the frisbee, and implicitly assumes that the pressure is constant at the flat part of the frisbee, so that the rotational motion of the frisbee is propogated to the air by the mediation of viscosity alone ($\eta$ in the equations). I'm not quite sure that this is correct.

Therefore, i'd like to know if my model is correct, and if not, how to correct it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add how your angle of attack $\theta$ is measured. Normally we use $\alpha$ for it and define it to be zero for a horizontal orientation of the lift-producing surface. And, of course, without translational motion there is no attack, hence no angle of attack, only inclination. Since the centrifugal acceleration of air due to friction is the same on both surfaces, there should be no lift for the disk without translational motion.

Comment: @PeterKämpf - the physical cause for the lift can be explained in this way: very close to the flat part of the frisbee, there is a boundary layer that flows radialy out, and when this radialy moving air reaches the edge of the flat part, it's than deflected downward by the conical part of the frisbee, thereby creating lift according to Newton's third law. I'll add this explanation in my question.